# Delegating privately declared variables to a public scope

Tags: swift

I come with an issue - I am trying to parse an html body content such that I can access the raw text of the HTML response. Issues I am running into is due to the lack of knowledge in handling scoped variables - for example

```
let _RequestPartsURL = URL(string:"http://xxxxxxx.on.ca/getData.aspx?requestType=Tech")!;
let _WebSession = URLSession.shared;
class _WebSessionCredentials {
    let _RequestURL       = _RequestPartsURL;
    let _InstancedSession = _WebSession;
    let _InstancedTask    = _WebSession.dataTask(with: _RequestPartsURL) { data,response,error in
        if error != nil {
            // Error
            print("Client Error!");
            return;
        };
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
            print("Server Error!");
            return;
        };
        guard let mime     = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
            print("Wrong mime type!");
            return;
        };
        var htmlbody = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!;
        print(htmlbody.utf8)
    };
};
_WebSessionCredentials()._InstancedTask.resume();
_WebSessionCredentials()._InstancedTask.htmlbody;
 Error: Value of type 'URLSessionDataTask' has no member 'htmlbody
```

When I go to access the raw data which is located in `data!` I understand that the variable is local to the `let _InstancedTask` but why is accessing the data through `_WebSessionCredentials()._InstancedTask.htmlbody;`an incorrect statement - Aren't I saying I want to access `htmlbody` in `_InstancedTask` from `_WebSessionCredentials()` ?

I come from Python so I am running into a bit of an resolving how I should instance and use data located in my classes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `_InstancedTask` is an object of type `URLSessionDataTask`. The problem lies in that `URLSessionDataTask` does not have a property called `htmlbody`. The `htmlbody` that you are referring to lies in a block that is called asynchronously

Comment: @kezi So its destroyed when the block of code is done executing? How would I preserve this value to be passed to a variable declared outside of that block or the class as a whole? Any recommendations?

Comment: It depends on what you plan on doing with your class. You could initialize the class with a block that gets called on completion. if you are using the latest beta Swift you could use reactive programming with Combine. The worst thing you could do, but might be acceptable depending on your circumstances, is to download synchronously using `Data.init(contentsOf:options:)`

Comment: @kezi I am using the class a portion of a greater application that will deliver results queried from a MSSql DB - I am trying to create this class as a way to have a standardized way of consuming any kind of URL - and subsequently the data that comes with it - Hence also why I want to be able to access 'data!' from outside of the class - So I may pass it to a UILabel For example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `htmlbody` variable is a variable local to the `URLSessionDataTask` block. If you want access to `htmlbody` I would suggest to have `htmlbody` as an instance variable on the class itself and initialise it in that block. So your class would look like:

```
class _WebSessionCredentials {
let _RequestURL       = _RequestPartsURL
let _InstancedSession = _WebSession
var htmlbody: String?
let _InstancedTask    = _WebSession.dataTask(with: _RequestPartsURL) { [weak self] (data,response,error) in
    if error != nil {
        // Error
        print("Client Error!")
        return
    }
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
        print("Server Error!")
        return
    }
    guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
        print("Wrong mime type!");
        return
    }
    self.htmlbody = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    print(htmlbody.utf8)
  }
}
```

Now you can access `htmlbody` by calling `.htmlbody` on your `_WebSessionCredentials()` object.

I would suggest a few changes to the code to be a little more Swift-y:

```
class WebSessionCredentials {
    static let requestURL = URL(string:"http://xxxxxxx.on.ca/getData.aspx?requestType=Tech")!
    var htmlbody: String?
    var instancedTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    static var sharedInstance = WebSessionCredentials()

    init() {
       self.instancedTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: WebSessionCredentials.requestURL) { [weak self] (data,response,error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Error
            print("Client Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
            print("Server Error!")
            return
        }
        guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
            print("Wrong mime type!");
            return
        }

        if let htmlData = data, let htmlBodyString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: .utf8) {
           self?.htmlbody = htmlBodyString
           print(htmlbody.utf8)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now you can do what I think you were originally trying to do like so:

```
WebSessionCredentials.sharedInstance.instancedTask.resume()
WebSessionCredentials.sharedInstance.htmlbody
```

Swift naming conventions don't have underscores, and follow camel case. I have created a singleton called `sharedInstance` since you seemed to be initialising `_WebSessionCredentials` twice and expecting it to reference the same object. Global variables are also not preferred, so I have made your `_RequestPartsURL` into a class variable called `requestURL`. This can be accessed by calling `WebSessionCredentials.requestURL`.

The `[weak self]` is making sure that your reference to `self` is a `weak` reference so as to not create a strong reference cycle. In a network request like the one you have here, the network request can be completed when the `WebSessionCredentials` object has already been deallocated. If you have a `strong` or `unowned` reference to `self` at that point your application will crash. The `[weak self]` also ensures that when the completion block is called your reference to self is `Optional` and you can safely access `htmlbody` by calling `self?.htmlbody`. Whereas if the call were `self.htmlbody` the app would crash.

Comment: Excellent explanation - I am very thankful for that! Regarding 'weak self' what is that exactly. I understand self but what exactly are you trying to say there the variable of self is weak therefore can be 'nil'?

Comment: Sorry! I'll edit my answer for an explanation of the [weak self].

Comment: I also seem to be getting an error around the last if statement - self.htmlbody throws Value of optional type 'WebSessionCredentials?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'htmlbody' of wrapped base type 'WebSessionCredentials'

Comment: Thank you very much brother for your help

Comment: Just updated the answer with an explanation of the `[weak self]` and a slight correction to the code! It should work now.