# Webservice returning nil

Tags: swift

I am having trouble populating a UITextField with my returnHTML data that I get from my web-service.

If I have my web-service such that:

```
import Foundation;
class WebSessionCredentials {
    static let requestURL = URL(string:"xxxx.on.ca/getData.aspx?requestType=Tech")!
    var htmlbody: String?
    var instancedTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    static var sharedInstance = WebSessionCredentials()
    init() {
        self.instancedTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: WebSessionCredentials.requestURL) { [weak self] (data,response,error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Error
                print("Client Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("Server Error!")
                return
            }
            guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
                print("Wrong mime type!");
                return
            }
            
            if let htmlData = data, let htmlBodyString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: .utf8) {
                self?.htmlbody = htmlBodyString;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Through this I should be able to access the returned HTML response through `WebSessionCredentials.sharedInstance.htmlbody;`

Verifying this in playground I seem to be getting the correct response within the class but when calling htmlbody from outside the class I get a nil response - I am out of ideas in terms of how to send that HTML string that I get from the class to outside the function. This question is  built off another question I have posted a couple days earlier -> [Delegating privately declared variables to a public scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976356/delegating-privately-declared-variables-to-a-public-scope/56976928?noredirect=1#comment100490328_56976928)

Thanks,

Comment: `dataTask` works asynchronously. It's bad practice to run asynchronous tasks in `init` methods. And this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.

Comment: @vadian Any recommendations for implementing the desired functionality? Further the semicolons are just for my own readability - just so I also don't lose the habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than implementing the `dataTask` in the `init` method add a method `run` with completion handler

```
class WebSessionCredentials {

    enum WebSessionError : Error {
        case badResponse(String)
    }

    static let requestURL = URL(string:"xxxx.on.ca/getData.aspx?requestType=Tech")!
    static var sharedInstance = WebSessionCredentials()

    func run(completion : @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
        let instancedTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: WebSessionCredentials.requestURL) { (data,response,error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Error
                print("Client Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                completion(.failure(WebSessionError.badResponse("Server Error!")))
                return
            }
            guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
                completion(.failure(WebSessionError.badResponse("Wrong mime type!")))
                return
            }
            completion(.success(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!))
        }
        instancedTask.resume()
    }
}
```

And use it

```
WebSessionCredentials.sharedInstance.run { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let htmlBody): print(htmlBody)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - if I you don't mind can you share with me some resources on the implementation strategy you used? What kind of things should I learn in the Swift Doc's or general programming knowledge to understand how you implemented that

Comment: A completion handler to handle asynchronously received data is a very common pattern and the parameter type is the new generic `Result` type of Swift although you can declare the enum yourself in older Swift versions.

Comment: Once again - I appreciate your expertise on the matter. An interesting point of note for me is `case .success(let htmlBody): print(htmlBody)` and `case .failure(let error): print(error)` in these lines the enum you have defined - you are essentially saying that when the response is successful you create a new constant called `htmlBody` and then you use it such that `print(htmlBody)` is executed? If I had label can I do something like `myLabel.text = htmlBody`?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) you see that the enum cases are declared with associated values. In the switch `htmlBody` is the result on success and `error` is the result on failure. You can assign `htmlBody` directly to your label but add a `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure to update the UI on the main thread

Comment: Thank you @vadian - My new questions are quickly leaving the scope of the original discussion. I appreciate all your help - now off to learn about using DispatchQueue !